# Converting dreamweaver to WordPress

Tags: design

I created a WordPress site than needs a much needed facelift and I want to work with a designer who uses dreamweaver. We looked at tweaking my existing WordPress site but it would require coding expertise that neither of us have (for example we want each page to have a different header image and we don't want a top navigation menu on the home page).

Is the best course of action for him to create the site entirely in dreamweaver and then hire someone else to convert it or export it back into WordPress? I would like to be able to update it myself once the conversion is complete.

Thanks,

Wendy

Comment: While this isn't a WordPress question directly. What you should do, is hire a designer who designs in a Graphic Design application (i.e Photoshop) then hire an expert WordPress developer to create a theme that has all of the required customisability you would require. Alternatively look at paying for a theme on a marketplace such as Theme Forest or Theme Garden etc.

Comment: You [could](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/dw_wordpress_pt1.html) probably do this, but the amount of coding expertise you need is pretty much the same as if you would edit the theme in any other code editor.

Setting up a WordPress preview with Dreamweaver is probably harder and more time-consuming than learning the basics of HTML & CSS, which would take you minutes to understand. And you won't be able to fully edit your theme in DW's WYSIWYG mode, which I assume is what you want since you're using that app in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Just design it on Photoshop ( or any graphics program) and then convert it to WordPress, there is no need for any middle coding in this situation.

**GOOD** graphics --->WordPress

**BAD** graphics-->dreamweaver---> WordPress